# How to Serialize Interface inside Serializable Bean

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Serializable Bean class which consist of an interface instance `dozerMapper` of `MapperIF`. Everything was working fine before I added `PersistentManager` in the context.xm file in my tomcat server. With the `PersistentManager` I am storing all the Objects in session as a file to the folder. But after i added the `PersistentManager` it started throwing `NotSerializableException` because of the MapperIF interface inside my Bean class. Adding `transient` keyword to the MapperIF could solve the `NotSerializableException`, But it ends up with the `NullPointerException` as the  dozerMapper.map is coming null in the below code. So how can i handle this situation for serializing my bean class.

```
@Autowired
private transient MapperIF dozerMapper;

    public Preferences getUiPreferences() {
    if (this.uiPreferences == null) {
        this.uiPreferences = ((Preferences) this.dozerMapper.map(
                getPrefernces(), Preferences.class));
    }
    return this.uiPreferences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MapperIF` interface (or its Dozer 5.x replacement `Mapper`) does not extend `Serializable`.  Its standard implementation classes do not implement it either.  Therefore the standard implementations are not going to be serializable.

I can think of ways to solve this:

- Don't put the `MapperIF` reference into an object that you save in the session.  It doesn't really belong there.  Here's what the javadocs for the `DozerBeanMapper` class say:

  > This should be used/defined as a singleton within your application. This class performs several one-time initializations and loads the custom xml mappings, so you will not want to create many instances of it for performance reasons. Typically a system will only have one `DozerBeanMapper` instance per VM. If you are using an IOC framework (i.e Spring), define the Mapper as singleton="true". If you are not using an IOC framework, a `DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper` convenience class has been provided in the Dozer jar.

  This implies that you shouldn't *need* to put a `MapperIF` object into a session.
- Declare the field as `transient` and implement a custom `readObject` method that will repopulate the field (from somewhere) when you deserialize.
- Implement your own custom `MapperIF` / `Mapper` class that is serializable.  (I haven't looked, but this could be a lot of work ... or impossible.)

Comment: Erm ... no.  Look for a tutorial on Spring singletons.